# How to run nodejs and nginx with dyanmic Docker Option?

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm fairly new to node and nginx. I've a task of building a simple webserver which host dynamic contents. A very crucial part of the webserver is to take inputs from user about ports to be used , any custom domain to be used (in place of localhost)  , SSL certificates etc. from installer [***Its supposed to be built for docker*** ] but I have no idea how to execute a script such that is passes the variable entered by user ( like $SERVER_URI) to nginx.conf and node file and overwrite current data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to create a config file and read the value from them so everything will be dynamic.

Here is how you can achieve SSL certificate and other ENV and port dynamically also docker name and image name will be get and set.

> **Create file docker.config** which contain ports, ENV, path mapping, hosts values and links if you wish to link container. leave them blank
>   if you do not need them. remove `host_port:container_port` this entry
>   just for comment purpose.

**docker.config**

```
START_PORT_MAPPINGS
host_port:container_port
8080:80
END_PORT_MAPPINGS

START_PATH_MAPPINGS
/path_to_code/:/var/www/htlm/test
/path_to_nginx_config1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
/path_to_ssl_certs:/container_path_to_Certs
END_PATH_MAPPINGS

START_LINKING
db:db-server
END_LINKING

START_HOST_MAPPINGS
test.com:192.168.1.23
test2.com:192.168.1.23
END_HOST_MAPPINGS

START_ENV_VARS
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234
OTHER_ENV_VAR=value
END_ENV_VARS
```

> **create start.sh** this will read the values from **docker.config** and will run command your docker container.

**Need two arguments 1st: docker name and 2nd: image name.**

```
    function read_connfig() {

  docker_name="${1}"
  input="docker.config"


  option_key=$(echo "${2}" | cut -d':' -f1)
  config_name=$(echo "${2}" | cut -d':' -f2)
  post_fix=$(echo "${2}" | cut -d':' -f3)

  while IFS=$' \t\n\r' read -r line; do

    if [[ $line == END_"${config_name}" ]] ; then
        read_prop="no"
    fi

    if [[ $read_prop == "yes" ]] ; then
        echo -n "${option_key}${line}${post_fix} "
    fi

    if [[ $line == START_"${config_name}" ]] ; then
        read_prop="yes"
    fi
  done < "$input"

}
function get_run_configs() {
  docker_name=${1}
  declare -a configs=("-p :PORT_MAPPINGS:" "-v :PATH_MAPPINGS:" "--add-host=:HOST_MAPPINGS:" "-e :ENV_VARS:" "--link :LINKING:")
  local run_command=""

  for config in "${configs[@]}"
  do
    config_vals=($(read_connfig "${docker_name}" "${config}"))
    if [ !  -z  "${config_vals}" ];
    then
      for config_val in "${config_vals[@]}"
      do
        run_command="${run_command} ${config_val}"
      done
      else
        echo >&2 "No config found for ${config}"
    fi
  done
  echo "${run_command}"
}
container_name=$1;
image_name=$2
docker_command=$(get_run_configs $docker_name)
echo $docker_command
docker run --name $container_name $docker_command -dit $image_name
```

Resulting command will be. `./start.sh test test`

```
docker run --name test  -p host_port:container_port -p 8080:80 -v /path_to_code/:/var/www/htlm/test -v /path_to_nginx_config1:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf -v /path_to_ssl_certs:/container_path_to_Certs --add-host=test.com:192.168.1.23 --add-host=test2.com:192.168.1.23 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e OTHER_ENV_VAR=value --link db:db-server -dit test
```

Comment: Thank you ! I guess this is working but can I add the scripts to dockerfile to enable automatic execution of scripts at start of an image

Comment: yeah but not this script you can run this script from host or you need docker dind then you need to copy script to your docker file and run that script at boot up time

Comment: But how do I allow user to change port ? Can I (for e.g.) create a variable $PORT_TO_EXPOSED and allow user to input variable to the file using GUI (maybe ?) with node.js script

Comment: For every docker container create docker.config instead of env. The docker.config do the same

Comment: I’m sorry but I don’t know how can the user change ports etc.

Comment: user will only need to change docker.config not any thing else